# jQuery ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone tell me why the document ready function needs a call to function first please? I've been told that the setTimeout in the first below example (which does not work) would be evaluated and passed to ready, but I don't see what the difference would be for the function call in the second example (which works)?

```
$(document).ready(
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            $('#set_3').innerfade({
                animationtype: 'fade',
                speed: 'slow',
                timeout: 3000,
                type: 'sequence',
                containerheight: '180' });
        },
        2000);
);


$(document).ready( 
    function(){  
        setTimeout(
            function(){ 
                $('#set_3').innerfade({  
                    animationtype: 'fade',
                    speed: 'slow', 
                    timeout: 3000, 
                    type: 'sequence', 
                    containerheight: '180' }); 
            }, 
            2000);
    }
);
​
```

Answer (score 6):

The latter defines a function that will be called when the document is ready, and passes this as the argument to `$(document).ready()`. In the former, the argument that is passed to `$(document).ready()` is the result of evaluating your `setTimeout` command, so yes, in the first case, the `setTimeout` call is immediate.

Comment: ...which can lead to erros if the  $('#set_3') element is not loaded after 2 seconds. Generally, first call makes absolutely no sence to me.

Comment: ...in the first case, there is no point for the [`$(document).ready();`](http://api.jquery.com/ready) as it doesn't know what to do with the integer returned by [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a callback to `ready()`. `setTimeout` doesn't return a callback, the way you have it it gets executed *immediately*, and its result passed as an argument to the `ready` function. That is not what you want.

Just wrap it in a `function() { }` and it'll work.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider a simpler example.

```
function f (g) {
   g();
}
```

This function `f` accepts a *function* parameter `g` and calls it. Therefore, we expect `g` to be a function.

Now

```
f (alert("Wrong"));
```

is equivalent to

```
var param = alert("Wrong");
f(param);
```

You see, in the first line the alert box (as the statement is evaluated) will be shown and return `undefined` to `param`. But `f` expects a function, not an `undefined`.

A function is needed. One way is to create one:

```
function param () { alert("Right"); }
f(param);
```

But Javascript also supports anonymous functions, in the form

```
var param = function () { alert("Right"); }
f(param);
```

Now eliminate the `param` variable you'll get

```
f(function () { alert("Right"); });
```

---

Corresponding to your question, `f` is `$(document).ready` and `alert` is that `setTimeout` function.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is expecting an anonymous function it can call.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Saying it needs an anonymous function is somewhat misleading. Doing the following works just fine: `function namedf(){alert("hello"})); $(document).ready(namedef)` While, once passed in, jquery won't call the function by name, that function isn't truly anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

You need pass in a delegate to the ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Or simply:

```
$(function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you provide is a callback which is executed when the DOM has been ready (the entire page may not be loaded yet).

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work, at least not the same way. Eventhough the timer is started in the first example, it doesn't start when the `ready` event happens.

In the first example the `ready` method is called with the result from the `setTimeout` method. As `setTimeout` returns a handle for the timeout and not a delegate that the `ready` method can use, it's the same as:

```
setTimeout(
    function(){
        $('#set_3').innerfade({
            animationtype: 'fade',
            speed: 'slow',
            timeout: 3000,
            type: 'sequence',
            containerheight: '180' });
    },
    2000);

$(document).ready();
```

So, the `setTimeout` method is called immediately, and the call to `ready` has no effect at all.